# Compare Nodejs generated bcrypt hash in PHP

Tags: php, node.js, hash, bcrypt

Just to know about bcrypt hash comparison in different platforms, that I have one brypt hash which is generated at Nodejs server, now I am moving to PHP, I want to know about is this possible to compare already created bcrypt hashes(generated in Nodejs) in PHP

Node JS Code:

```
function hash(password) {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    bcrypt.hash(password, 8, function(err, hashedPassword) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        fulfill(hashedPassword);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Input : `simha`

output: `$2a$10$c/EwGsRkoV4XHmsOJYWZ6.LurbDUFW.eq83SI8eu5JaMOsr6PyLrm`

Is it possible to generate the ouput hash using input `simha` in PHP

I am trying the below one, but it is generating different hash

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) 
//output : $2y$10$CfihL9RipXW88JAVvlyFlegM5BAyD5xQmNutjm9KepeXUn5cAwIX2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't expect them to match, at least by default. This is because for both functions, a random salt is chosen every time you hash a value.

The important thing is not that the hash outputs match, but that they still validate. So you could take the hashed output from node.js and use it with [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) in PHP for example, and it should validate.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working. Just roaming around password_hash, now cleared the concept. Thanks